# Proof of an inequality involving general triangles

Tags: geometry, inequality

In any triangle the following inequality holds:
$$\dfrac{9abc}{a+b+c}\ge4S\sqrt{3}$$
where $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle and $S$ the area.
How the previous inequality can be proven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Euler, we have $S=\frac{abc}{4R}$, hence the inequality is equivalent to:
$$ \frac{9}{a+b+c}\geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{R} \tag{1} $$
or to:
$$ a+b+c\leq 3\sqrt{3}\,R \tag{2}$$
that is just an instance of the isoperimetric inequality: among all the triangles inscribed in a circle with radius $R$, the equilateral triangles have the greatest perimeter. $(2)$ is also equivalent to:
$$ \sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C) \leq \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag{3} $$
[that is well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities#Angles), and a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality): the sine function is concave over $(0,\pi)$.